# Android Studio Build Error: Execution task ':app.processDebugResources'

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I'm installing Android Studio 3.1.2 and I am getting the following error message for execution task ':app.processDebugResources'.

```
Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'
```

Comment: Post your whole `build.gradle`

Comment: I guess you have a repeated lib